# MEAN stack resfulAPI multiple dbs / collections

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

I am a begginner to MEAN and I have a MEAN stack application that pulls data into one table on one HTML page but now I want to pull data from two mongo db's or collections into another table on the same page but not sure what's the best way to go about it. Do i need to use two ng-controllers? Any help much appreciated thanks.

HTML:

```
<div class="risklog" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<table class="logs">
  <thead class="logheaders">
    <tr>
      <th>RiskID</th>         
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Probability</th>
      <th>Impact</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
      <th>Owner</th>
      <th>RiskLevel</th>
      <th>Action</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead class="logheaders">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input ng-model="risk.RiskID"></td>
      <td><input ng-model="risk.Description"></td>
      <td><select ng-model="risk.Probability">
            <option value="High">High</option>
            <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="Low">Low</option>
      </td>
      <td><select ng-model="risk.Impact">
            <option value="High">High</option>
            <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="Low">Low</option>
      </td>
      <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="risk.Actions"></td>
      <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="risk.Owner"></td>
      <td><select class="form-control" ng-model="risk.RiskLevel">
            <option value="High">High</option>
            <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="Low">Low</option>
      </td>
      <td><button class="btn-blue" ng-click="addRisk()">Add Risk</button></td>
      <td><button class="btn-blue" ng-click="update()">Update</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="btn-blue" ng-click="deselect()"> Clear </button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="risk in risklog">
      <td>{{risk.RiskID}}</td>
      <pre><td>{{risk.Description}}</td></pre>
      <td>{{risk.Probability}}</td>
      <td>{{risk.Impact}}</td>
      <td>{{risk.Actions}}</td>
      <td>{{risk.Owner}}</td>
      <td>{{risk.RiskLevel}}</td>
      <td><button class="btn-red" ng-click="remove(risk._id)">Remove</button></td>
      <td><button class="btn-orange" ng-click="edit(risk._id)">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JS controller

```
    ar myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    console.log("Hello World from controller");


var refresh = function() {
  $http.get('/contactlist').success(function(response) {
    console.log("I got the data I requested");
    $scope.risklog = response;
    $scope.risk = "";
  });
};

refresh();

$scope.addRisk = function() {
  console.log($scope.risk);
  $http.post('/contactlist', $scope.risk).success(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    refresh();
  });
};

$scope.remove = function(id) {
  console.log(id);
  $http.delete('/contactlist/' + id).success(function(response) {
    refresh();
  });
};

$scope.edit = function(id) {
  console.log(id);
  $http.get('/contactlist/' + id).success(function(response) {
    $scope.risk = response;
  });
};  

$scope.update = function() {
  console.log($scope.risk._id);
  $http.put('/contactlist/' + $scope.risk._id, $scope.risk).success(function(response) {
    refresh();
  })
};

$scope.deselect = function() {
  $scope.risk = "";
}

}]);﻿
```

Server JS

```
    var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('risklog', ['risklog']);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/contactlist', function (req, res) {
  console.log('I received a GET request');

  db.risklog.find(function (err, docs) {
    console.log(docs);
    res.json(docs);
  });
});

app.post('/contactlist', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  db.risklog.insert(req.body, function(err, doc) {
    res.json(doc);
  });
});

app.delete('/contactlist/:id', function (req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  console.log(id);
  db.risklog.remove({_id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)}, function (err, doc) {
    res.json(doc);
  });
});

app.get('/contactlist/:id', function (req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  console.log(id);
  db.risklog.findOne({_id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)}, function (err, doc) {
    res.json(doc);
  });
});

app.put('/contactlist/:id', function (req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  console.log(req.body.name);
  db.risklog.findAndModify({
    query: {_id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)},
    update: {$set: {RiskID: req.body.RiskID, Description: req.body.Description, Probability: req.body.Probability, Impact: req.body.Impact, Actions: req.body.Actions, Owner: req.body.Owner, RiskLevel: req.body.RiskLevel}},
    new: true}, function (err, doc) {
      res.json(doc);
    }
  );
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Server running on port 3000");
```

Comment: All you need to do is create a service to pull data and assign data to model on controller, then in your HTML do whatever you want with the data as you did with a current set, no brainer ;)

Comment: Don't know how to do this  and can't find any examples :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it same way you already do it for one set of data

```
var refresh = function () {
    $http.get('/contactlist').success(function (response) {
        console.log("I got the data I requested");
        $scope.risklog = response;
        $scope.risk = "";
    });
};

var loadSomethingElse = function () {
    $http.get('/somethingElse').success(function (response) {
        console.log("I got the something else I requested");
        $scope.somethingElseOnScope = response;
    });
};
```

> and then in html

```
<tr ng-repeat="something in somethingElseOnScope">
  <td>{{something.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: thanks, but then do I have to create another app.get in the server?

Comment: yes, yes it have to, your server should respond with data for `/somethingElse` how else you can load it? :)

Comment: one more question, how would I do it for a collection in a mongo db?

Comment: What do you mean for a collection?

Comment: pull data from a collection(table) within a mongo database

Comment: 'db.risklog.find(function (err, docs) { console.log(docs); res.json(docs); });' like this where 'risklog' is your collection and 'db' is your mongodb pointer